# Xsd import doesn't work

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd, intellisense

I'm trying to use an xsd defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd#. I saved that definition as one xsd file to my disk and change the import in a different xsd to use it but the visual studio doesn't detected or give me any clue by intellsense. i also set the visual studio menu option xml >menu > schemas and select the file, but doesn't work.

My xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://x/y/z/w/"
xmlns="http://x/y/z/w/"
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">

  <!--<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd#"/>-->
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="file:/B:/Test.xsd" id="ds"></xs:import>

<xs:element name="elementX">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>        
        <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

The import i want to use is allocated in http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd#

my question: is there any way to change the definition in order to appears in the intellsense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: B it's a partition in my disk.

Comment: I don't think you can assign the drive letter `B:` to a partition on a fixed disk. Also the proper notation is `file://`, note the double forward slash.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Perhaps you can with `subst` ;p

Comment: Actually i'm not pretty sure if it is a partition or it's a disk but there it is. it really does matter?

Comment: I tried adding the double forward slash but doesn't work